# Utilizar if() dentro de .catch() - erro: unexpected token if

Tags: javascript, node.js

É o seguinte

Sou novato em javascript e não estou sabendo lidar com esse erro. Estou tentando chamar uma função e colocando um `.catch()` para evitar o erro ***UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning*** logo após ela, porém gostaria de fazer uma verificação de 'caso ocorra um erro, faça isso'.

Tentei fazer essa verificação utilizando um `if()`, porém meu  console para devido à ***SyntaxError: unexpected token if***. Já tentei utilizar `try...catch`, mas ocorreu o erro *UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning* que eu falei... Meu código se assemelha a este:

```
    //um pouco de código aqui

    function(args).catch(error => console.log(error),
    if(error){
         //Código que deve ser executado caso ocorra erro
    });

    //um pouco mais de código aqui
```

Resumindo, é possível colocar um `if()` dentro de um `.catch()`? Existe uma forma melhor de fazer essa verificação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sintaxe de função flecha (*arrow function*)  está errada. Podes fazer isso assim (assumindo que essa função retorna uma Promise):

```
minhaFn('foo').catch(error => {
    if(error){
         console.log(error);
         // Outro código que deve ser executado caso ocorra erro
    }
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/zkodkf7b/

```js
function minhaFn(nr) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // isto vai dar asneira pois a variavel "naodeclarado" não está declarada
        resolve(nr / naodeclarado);
    });
}

minhaFn(20).catch(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.message.includes('is not defined')) {
            alert('Há variáveis não defenidas!');
        }
    }
}).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Sergio! você me tirou de um aperto =D